# How to increase the size of infowindow in google maps android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing a project where the title and descriptions have to be displayed. But the issue is the text in the description is little lengthy which is not shown when we click on the marker. I want to size of the snippet to show the full description else need some other option?

```
  @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class GoogleActivity extends
  FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;    private static final long
  MIN_TIME = 700;   private static final float MIN_DISTANCE = 800;


    // Google Map   private GoogleMap googleMap;    LatLng myPosition;

    // All static variables     static final String URL =
  "http://webersspot.accountsupport.com/gmaptrial/onedb/phpsqlajax_genxml.php";
    // XML node keys

    static final String KEY_PID = "pro"; // parent node     static final
  String KEY_NAME = "Name";     static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION =
  "Description";    static final String KEY_LAT = "Latitude";   static
  final String KEY_LONG = "Longitude";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String   storeMapData = new
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String  ();     private ShareActionProvider
  mShareActionProvider;

    @Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();


        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);  // Hybrid for
  satellite with place name


        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);  // enable user location
  button.       googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(null) ;

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true); // enable road 



        /*

     // Get Location Manager and check for GPS & Network location
  services
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
              !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
          // Build the alert dialog
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
          builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
          builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
          });
          Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
          alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
          alertDialog.show();
        }        */





        new LongOperation().execute("");        new
  MapOperation().execute(googleMap);


        locationManager = (LocationManager)
  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
  MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this); //You can also use
  LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER and LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER     



    }



    public List<HashMap<String, String   prepareData(){

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String   menuItems = new
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String  ();         //List<HashMap<String,
  String    menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String  ();

        XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();         String xml =
  parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML         Document doc =
  parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PID);        // looping
  through all item nodes <item          for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength();
  i++) {            // creating new HashMap             HashMap<String, String  map = new
  HashMap<String, String ();            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            System.out.println("OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO  :::
  "+e.getAttribute(KEY_NAME));          // adding each child node to HashMap
  key =  value

            map.put(KEY_NAME, e.getAttribute(KEY_NAME).toString());
            map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION
  ,e.getAttribute(KEY_DESCRIPTION).toString());             map.put(KEY_LAT,
  e.getAttribute(KEY_LAT).toString());          map.put(KEY_LONG
  ,e.getAttribute(KEY_LONG).toString());


            // adding HashList to ArrayList             menuItems.add(map);
            storeMapData = menuItems;

        }       return menuItems;

    }

    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {       
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String   processData = storeMapData;



        System.out.println( "kjkasdc   "+processData);

        for (int i=0; i< processData.size(); i++){


            final double lat =
  Double.parseDouble(processData.get(i).get(KEY_LAT));
            System.out.println("MAP LAT :::::::::::::::::::::::::  "+lat);
            final double lon = 
  Double.parseDouble(processData.get(i).get(KEY_LONG));
            System.out.println("MAP LON :::::::::::::::::::::::::  "+lon);
            final String address = processData.get(i).get(KEY_DESCRIPTION);
            System.out.println("MAP ADDRESS ::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
  "+address);           final String name = processData.get(i).get(KEY_NAME);
            System.out.println("MAP ADDRESS :::::::::::::::::::::::::  "+name);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                    Marker melbourne = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(MELBOURNE)
                            .title(name)

                            .snippet(address)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
                    melbourne.showInfoWindow();


                    //      map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(name).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));






                }           });

        }   }



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")     @Override   public boolean
  onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);     

        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)
  menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();

        /** Setting a share intent */
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }    

    /** Returns a share intent */   private Intent
  getDefaultShareIntent(){              Intent intent = new
  Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);       intent.setType("text/plain");       
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Download");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Download Hill Top Beauty Parlour
  App - Maroli from Google Play Store: 
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=beauty.parlour.maroli");
            return intent;  }


    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String  {
        @Override       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {     
                prepareData();                  return "Executed";      }       @Override       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
            System.out.println("Executed");         }       @Override       protected void
  onPreExecute() {                      System.out.println("Execution started"); 
            }       @Override       protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

            System.out.println("     -- -- -- "+values);        }   }

    private class MapOperation extends AsyncTask<GoogleMap, Void, String 
  {         @Override       protected String doInBackground(GoogleMap... params) {
            GoogleMap map = params[0];          onMapReady(map);                return
  "Executed";       }       @Override       protected void onPostExecute(String
  result) {                         System.out.println(result);         }       @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {         
            System.out.println("Execution started");                    }       @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

            System.out.println("     -- -- -- "+values);        }   }

    class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

        private final View myContentsView;

        MyInfoWindowAdapter(){          myContentsView =
  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);         }

        @Override       public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            TextView tvTitle =
  ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
            tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());             TextView tvSnippet =
  ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());




            return myContentsView;      }

        @Override       public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {          // TODO
  Auto-generated method stub            return null;


                    }




    }

    @Override   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {      //
  TODO Auto-generated method stub       LatLng latLng = new
  LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate =
  CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    }


    @Override   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
  Bundle extras) {      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {        // TODO
  Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {       //
  TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




  }




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title" 

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"

             android:marqueeRepeatLimit="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp" />


</Relativelayout>
```

Comment: Can we see the `custom_info_contents` layout? Are the TextViews inside it using `WRAP_CONTENT`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom popup instead of snippet, something like this,

```
    private void showPopup(final Activity context, String address) {
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_layout, viewGroup);
    TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_address);
    textView.setText(address);
    // Creating the PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setFocusable(true);
    // Clear the default translucent background
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
    popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, mPoint.x, mPoint.y + 50 );
}
```

for demonstration install and check [here](https://github.com/HeshanSandeepa/Demo-GoogleMap)

Comment: have you checked the demonstration, if so update your question with what have you tried please